# Undefined Variable in PHP, after clearly defining it

Tags: php, variables, scope, undefined

I am receiving this error.
Undefined variable: db_conn in C:\xampp\htdocs\Wishlist\BookDao.php on line 15

```
<?php
require_once ('Book.php');
require_once ('DBConn.php');

class BookDao {
 private $db_conn;

function __construct() {
    $db_conn=new DBConn();
}

public function addBook(Book & $book) {
    //if (isbnAvailable($book -> getIsbn())) {
        $db_conn->connect();
        $db_conn -> setQuery("Insert into books(ISBN, Title, Author)
            Values('$book->getIsbn()','$book->getTitle()','$book->getAuthor()')");
        $db_conn -> executeQuery();
        $db_conn -> close();
        if (mysqli_num_rows($db_conn -> getResult())) {
            $db_conn -> freeResult();
            return true;
        } else {
            $db_conn -> freeResult();
            return false;
        }

}

public function isbnAvailable($isbn) {
    $db_conn -> connect();
    $db_conn -> setQuery("Select isbn from books where ISBN = ' . $isbn . '");
    $db_conn -> executeQuery();
    $db_conn -> close();
    if (mysqli_num_rows($db_conn -> getResult())) {
        $db_conn -> freeResult();
        return false;
    } else {
        $db_conn -> freeResult();
        return true;
    }
}

}
?>
```

It appears to be a scope issue but I am not sure, I am also new to PHP so it very well could be some silly mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are in a class context. To set and access your private class variable `$db_conn` you need to be using `$this->db_conn` everywhere.

In your constructor:

```
function __construct() {
    $this->db_conn=new DBConn();
}
```

And in all the other methods:

```
public function addBook(Book & $book) {
    $this->db_conn->connect();
    ...

public function isbnAvailable($isbn) {
    $this->db_conn->connect();
    ...
```

More on PHP classes and properties:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php
http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php

Comment: @KarmicDice Ha! I knew this one would be just a typing race. =)

Answer (score 2):

In PHP members need to be accessed via `$this`. So simply change `$db_conn` to `$this->db_conn` and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

use `$this->db_conn`

php classes require the $this preceding all class scoped variables.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this variable as `$this->db_conn` everywhere after defining it :)

Answer (score 0):

$db_conn is not global it exists as a class variable so you must reference it as such.

All instances of $db_conn should be $this->db_conn